# Difference between "lore" and "folklore"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between *lore* and *folklore*? What are the best examples where to use one and not the other?

Answer (score 4):

*Lore* is an [Old English word](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=lore&searchmode=none) that means something like [body of knowledge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lore) or the knowledge that is taught, which means it has been in the English lexicon for nigh on a thousand years.

[*Folklore*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/folklore), on the other hand, is much more recent.  It was [famously coined in 1846](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=folklore&searchmode=none) by [William Thoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Thoms), a British writer who was particularly interested in antiquities, including myths, fairy tales, and other sorts of oral traditions.

Folklore is related to lore, as you might expect, because folklore is exactly that: the lore of the folk. In other words, folklore is the body of knowledge that constitutes the myths, old wives' tales, legends, and other cultural foundations of a group of people.

Folklore can be contrasted with herb lore, for instance, which is the body of knowledge concerning the means of cultivating and using plants for medicinal purposes.

Answer (score 2):

**Lore** is a rather "dated" term for the "corpus of knowledge" in any particular area. It *is* still used today, but often in a slightly facetious way (the "arcane lore of software gurus", for example).

**Folklore** has survived as a somewhat "idiomatic" usage that's so common people often think of it as a single unit, so they don't register the "lore" component as archaic in the vocabulary sense.

But the referent of *folklore* itself implies "accumulated wisdom from the past" just as much as "...from ordinary folk, rather than recognised specialists and experts". So although there's a sense of the past in the word's *meaning*, the word itself doesn't sound particularly dated.

Comment: urban dictionary == folklore?

Comment: urban dictionary == [Folkjokeopus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Folkjokeopus-Roy-Harper/dp/B00004S6GY) most of the time. I've probably learnt more from Roy Harper than the website anyway - certainly enjoyed him more over the years! :)

Comment: Good answer, except that I would not say the "lore" is an archaic term. It is still actively used. For instance, "computer lore" is a fairly common term, as are "legal lore" and "political lore". For these areas, "lore" tends to be wisdom derived from true (or apocryphal) stories in the specific field.

Comment: @Jay Elston: If you think these are "normal" usages, I can't argue with your perception. But to me they're either slightly, or totally, facetious.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- do a search on those terms -- I think you will find that the word *lore* is still being used in a serious manner in many web articles and recent books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm with Jay on this one. *Lore* is still used in earnest.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Okay, well as usual I've somewhat overstated my case. I agree it's still sometimes used in earnest - but most commonly in respect of old/ancient accumulated wisdom, I feel. It's not likely to be used in earnest in the context of something like quantum mechanics, for example. I'll edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Folklore is also a discipline of study, in which the word folklore refers to informal and traditional cultural practices within a particular group, including things people say, do, and make.

Even though this thread is old, folklore is misrepresented a lot, so I wanted to put that out there.